# Session Variable not sending to next page

Tags: php, mysql, variables, session

I am trying to set a session variable for the location selected in the dropdown menu when the user hits submit.  The goal is to pass this variable to another php page so that I can display the drop down option they chose along with two values associated with it from a MYSQL table.

Below is a section of my code from my first php file.  It shows the dropdown that is created from a list of values from the MYSQL database along with where I am trying to set the session variable for the selected option.

```
session_start();
<form action="/locationsprocessing.php" method="post">
<select id="locations" name="locations"><? echo $option; ?></select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form> 
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
  $_SESSION['locations'] = $_POST['locations'];
  $_SESSION['animal']   = 'cat';
}
```

Below is my code from the second page where I call the session variables for display.  As you can see I have input another variable for testing purposes.  It is supposed to display "cat" and it does.

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['animal'];
echo $_SESSION['locations'];
```

**It may also be important to note that locationsprocessing.php runs a redirect using header.  But that is really all that file does.**

Am I missing something?  I have gone through countless different tuts and such and been staring at this code forever.  I can not see why it wo

Comment: Did you do session_start() in the script where you actually SET the values? And do it before ANY output was performed? you have to do that EVERYWHERE you use $_SESSION. PHP cannot magically reach back in time and turn on sessions because you tried to access a session variable that had been set in a script where session_start() was NOT called.

Comment: Sorry for not adding that part as well.  Yes I did session_start(); on every page with the variables.  I just forgot to copy and paste it here in this portion of the code.  I modified the code above to reflect that it is included in my code.

Answer (score 1):

you need start session in every pages where you need to use session:

```
<form action="/locationsprocessing.php" method="post">
<select id="locations" name="locations"><? echo $option; ?></select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form> 
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['locations'] = $_POST['locations'];
  $_SESSION['animal']   = 'cat';
}
```

Comment: I do have session_start(); on every page creating or using the variables.

Answer (score 0):

This may be going wrong: When you submit your form in the first piece of code from the questions, you are sending the data entered in the form to `/locationsprocessing.php`. You say that all that file does is redirecting to another page. That means the data entered in the form is effectively lost.

I think what you want to do is to remove the form processing code from the first piece of code, so with only this remaining:

```
session_start();
<form action="/locationsprocessing.php" method="post">
<select id="locations" name="locations"><? echo $option; ?></select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Then place that removed piece of code in `/locationsprocessing.php`, like this:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
  $_SESSION['locations'] = $_POST['locations'];
  $_SESSION['animal']   = 'cat';
  header('Location: ' . $destination);
}
```

`$destination` would be the path for the page with the second piece of code in the question.

Comment: I made your suggested change but it didn't work.  In fact, "cat" no longer shows up on the page that I am redirected to.  So essentially all that works now is the redirect.  I also tried putting the following code on the /locationsprocessing page but that didn't result in any outputs on the redirected page either.

    $_SESSION['locations'] = $_POST['locations'];
    $_SESSION['animal']   = 'cat';
    header('Location: http://www.instantassist.us/formcontact');

Comment: I did include session_start(); on the /locationsprocessing.php page as well even though you didn't mention that part in your answer.